# jest mock: how to use real module in a particular test?

Tags: jestjs

I try to mock some node modules for most of the tests, according to the [doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) I put the mock files into __mocks__ folder, but I also want to use the real module in a particular test, I have tried jest.unmock('some-module') but not working.

this is my project structure:

```
├──__mocks__
│   └── foo.js
│──doSomething.js
│──test.js
```

__mocks__/foo.js

```
const foo = jest.genMockFromModule('foo');
module.exports = foo;
```

doSomething.js

```
const foo = require('foo');

const doSomething = () => {
  foo.bar();
};

module.exports = doSomething;
```

test.js

```
const doSomething = require('./doSomething');

describe('Test', () => {
  it('doSomething() should call foo.bar', () => {
    doSomething();

    expect(foo.bar).toBeCalled();
  })

  it('use real foo module', () => {
    // How could I use real foo module in this test?

    jest.unmock('some-module'); // not working
    doSomething();
  })

})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `requireActual` to bypass the mocked module:

```
const doSomething = jest.requireActual('some-module');
doSomething();
```

Docs: https://jestjs.io/docs/en/bypassing-module-mocks